# Magento 2 SOAP API setSpecialPrice

Tags: magento2.2.2, rest-api, soap-api-v2, special-price, soap-api-v1

I am using Postman to post special-price but it's with REST API like so: Post URL: `http://magento2/rest/V1/products/special-price`

Payload:

```
{
 "prices": [
  {
   "price": 50.00,
   "store_id": 0,
   "price_from": "2017-07-15 00:00:00",
   "price_to": "2018-09-16 23:59:59",
   "sku": "1565_6338"
  }
 ]
}
```

REF: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/modules/catalog-pricing.html

This works as intended But Cannot find anywhere on the web references for the same call as SOAP API xml and payload examples and post url's.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the xml and I've got success bellow is the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:def="http://magento2/soap/all?
services=catalogSpecialPriceStorageV1">
 <soap:Body>
   <def:catalogSpecialPriceStorageV1UpdateRequest>
     <prices>
       <item>
        <price>50.00</price>
        <sku>1565_6338</sku>
        <storeId>0</storeId>
        <pirceFrom>2017-07-15 00:00:00</pirceFrom>
        <priceTo>2018-09-16 23:59:59</priceTo>
        </item>
      </prices>
    </def:catalogSpecialPriceStorageV1UpdateRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It add/updates special price successfully!